# How do I change the text of the "View" and "Edit" links on the user account page?

Tags: 8, users, theming

I'm looking for a way to change the text being displayed in the links on the user account page.

[image]

More specifically, I'm trying to change the text "View" and "Edit" to "View Profile" and "Edit Profile". Ideally, I would prefer a solution that allows me to do this in my `.theme` file via a **preprocessor** or a **hook** function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I know you can't do it in your theme, but it is possible to do in your module.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_local_tasks_alter().
 */
function mymodule_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $route_name) {
  // Change title for user profile's tabs.
  foreach ($data['tabs'] as &$tabs) {
    foreach ($tabs as &$tab) {
      $route_name = $tab['#link']['url']->getRouteName();
      if ($route_name == 'entity.user.canonical') {
        $tab['#link']['title'] = t('View profile');
      }
      elseif ($route_name == 'entity.user.edit_form') {
        $tab['#link']['title'] = t('Edit profile');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you man. I will try this when I get home and update you. It looks like it should work

Comment: @Adrian `Thank you man`??? her name is Maria...

Comment: @NoSssweat I am Jamaican. Man != "Male" to me. It is just a figure of speech in my country.

Comment: Works perfectly. Respect

Comment: I need to do same thing. but i added the above code i got an error. 'Call to a member function getRouteName() on a non-object in...'

Answer (score 0):

There is also a module that could be exactly what you need : [Tab Tamer](https://www.drupal.org/project/tabtamer).

Comment: The question was asked for Drupal 8, that module is Drupal 7 only and looks fairly inactive.

Comment: Sorry for that, I did not notice it was for D8.